# Outer glow turns gray scale on artboards with transparent background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, layer-style

As long there are no artboards in my PSD the outer glow works fine. But as soon as there are any, outer glow turns to grayscale over the transparent background of artboards.
These are my outer glow settings:

[image: outer glow settings]

Without artboards it works fine:

[image: layer list without artboard]
[image: outer glow without artboard]

With artboards and a non-transparent background it also works:

[image: layer list with artboard]
[image: outer glow with white artboard]

However, as soon as the artboard has a transparent background, the outer glow turns to gray scale:

[image: outer glow with artboard]

Comment: I am unable to replicate this issue with Photoshop CC2017/Mac -- [SEE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWXnI.png)

Comment: I can't replicate the issue either with Photoshop CC2018 on Window - [see example here](https://imgur.com/MZg0Y9M)

Comment: I'm currently running 20.0.7 on Windows

Comment: @IDarkCoder - then report the bug to Adobe (if it is one).  Not much we can do about it here if it is a bug.